# code coverage tools for validating the scripts

Tags: shell, code-coverage

Is there any way to validate the coverage of the shell scripts? I have project having lots of shell scripting, and need to ensure static analysis can be performed on the coverage for the shell scripts. Is there any tool available?

Comment: I added the shell tag (as it's not mentioned what kind of script in the title), but what kind of shell are you working with? I assume bash shell scripts or similar?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I seriously doubt that there could be any static code analysis performed on shell scripts - especially due to the fact that shell scripts *are* supposed to call *external* programs and based on what these external programs return - and there are myriads of external programs and external environment states. It's similar to the problem of static analysis of code heavily relying on `eval`-like mechanism, but shell scripting *is* all about eval-style programming.

However, there are some general pointers that could prove useful for "proper" validation, code coverage and documenting of shell scripts as major languages do:

- You can always run a script with `-x` (AKA `xtrace`) option - it will output trace looking like that to stderr:

  ```
  + log_end_msg 0
  + [ -z 0 ]
  + retval=0
  + log_end_msg_pre 0
  + :
  + log_use_fancy_output
  + TPUT=/usr/bin/tput
  + EXPR=/usr/bin/expr
  + [ -t 1 ]
  + [ xxterm != x ]
  + [ xxterm != xdumb ]
  ```
- Bash makes it possible to redirect this stream to external FD (using [BASH_XTRACEFD](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-BASH_005fXTRACEFD-178) variable) - that's much easier to parse in practice.
- It's not trivial, but it's possible to write a program that will find relevant pieces of code being executed using xtrace output and make you a fancy "code coverage" report - like what was called how many times, which pieces of code weren't run at all and thus lack test coverage.
- In fact, there's a wonderful tool named [shcov](http://code.google.com/p/shcov/) already written that uses this process - albeit it's somewhat simplistic and doesn't handle all possible cases very well (especially when we're talking about long and complex lines)
- Last, but not least - there's minimalistic [shelldoc](https://github.com/GreyCat/inq-web/blob/master/shelldoc) project (akin to [javadoc](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index-jsp-135444.html)) that helps generating documentation based on comments in shell scripts. Yep, that's a shameless plug :)

Comment: Static analysis?  Code coverage is generally determined by dynamic analysis, running a set of test cases and tracking the executed code. Your discussion of tracing stuff is at least in this vein.

Comment: There are 2 distinct approaches to code test coverage problem: dynamic  analysis (AKA instrumented run) - that's what you're talking about, and static. Static approach is usually more desirable, because it doesn't require tests, nor it depends on test quality. Although, I tend to agree that it's more or less "a holy grail" that many pursue, but in practice, instrumented runs are much more frequently used. I'd like to note that OP asked for static analysis, though.

Comment: Ah, yes he did.  I thought you were pushing it; my error. We're in agreement that you can do static analysis to get something like code coverage; a paper at SCAM 2009 I think showed static analysis of paths could get an approximation of what a coverage tool could do with good tests.  But there aren't any production tools out there that do this; the SCAM paper had a prototype.  So as a practical matter dynamic analysis is still king for this.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there are COTS tools available for test coverage, regardless of the scripting language and there are lots.

Another poster suggested an ad hoc approach that might work with some tools: get them to dump some trace data, and try to match that up with the actual code to get your coverage.   He says it sort of works... that's the problem with most hueristics.

Another approach one might take to construct a test coverage for your favorite scripting language is covered by my [technical paper on a general approach for building test coverage tools](http://www.semdesigns.com/Company/Publications/TestCoverage.pdf) using program transformations.  My company builds a line of such tools for more popular languages this way.

Answer (score 3):

You might try looking at [shcov](http://code.google.com/p/shcov/), a GPL v2-licensed Python-based tool. It seems to perhaps have been abandoned by the author, but does produce HTML-based graphical reports and seemed (in my limited testing) to be reasonably accurate in terms of coverage analysis.

Answer (score 3):

I have written the tool, that can do the coverage for the shell scripts, the name is **shAge** means shell script coverage, the project is hosted [here](https://code.google.com/p/sh-age/)

To do the Coverage if any shell scripts do the following

1. First Download the shAge.jar
2. Make sure you have you have jdk1.6 update 65 onwards
3. run the programe like

   java -jar shAge.jar  hello.sh
4. the content in the shell script will get executed and finally a report will be get generated
5. Report will be genared with the name of file in .html format **hello.sh.html**
6. Here is the sample output

[image]

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @SørenHoltenHansen My bad, i about to add lost my internet connection, any ways updated with the content